# Redirect to another page using radio buttons in php

Tags: php, html, redirect, radio-button

I have a page with 2 pictures (that are in reality radio buttons) and a button "proceed" I can choose one picture or another but when I click on the "proceed" button it doesn't redirect.

Here is the code of my form and my php process page

```
<body>
        <form method="post" action="process.php"> 
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="paymentCont">
                                <div class="headingWrap">
                                        <h3 class="headingTop text-center">Choisissez votre méthode de paiement</h3>    
                                        <p class="text-center">Sélectionnez votre méthode puis cliquez sur "Continuer"</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="paymentWrap">
                                    <div class="btn-group paymentBtnGroup btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">

                                        <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                                            <div class="method amex"></div>
                                            <input type="radio" name="paiement" value="paysafecard">
                                        </label>
                                         <label class="btn paymentMethod">
                                            <div class="method vishwa"></div>
                                            <input type="radio" name="paiement" value="paypal"> 
                                        </label>


                                    </div>        
                                </div>
                                <div class="footerNavWrap clearfix">
                                    <div class="btn btn-success pull-left btn-fyi"> <a href="https://beyoupronos.fr">RETOURNER SUR LE SITE</a></div>
                                    <div type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-fyi" value="Continuer" />Continuer</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

And my php :

```
<?

if(isset($_POST['paiement']) && ($_POST['paiement']) == "paysafecard"){

header("Location: http://www.example.com/non_company.php"); 

 }

elseif(isset($_POST['paiement']) && ($_POST['paiement']) == "")

{
   header("Location: http://www.example.com/company.php"); 
}

 else{
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/redirect_to_home.php"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: If you echo $_POST['paiement'] what does it show ?

Comment: <?

if(isset($_POST['paiement']) && ($_POST['paiement']) == "paysafecard"){

    echo $_POST['paiement'];

 }
?> Like that ? if yes it doesnt work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought typical mistake, not a div tag it is button tag or input tag(type submit) will submit the page

Change the following

```
<div type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-fyi" value="Continuer" />Continuer</div>
```

Into

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-fyi" value="Continuer" />Continuer</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use:

`<input type="submit" value="Continuer" />`

Or a tag`<button>Continuer</button>`

Besides of `<div type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-fyi" value="Continuer">Continuer</div>`

If you want to use a div you'll need to work with  JS a make this div to  submit